# setViewForPopUp(view) google api (11.6.0) google play sign in

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

So there are changes in the way of google play sign in long back when i implemented sign in it was throw `GoogleApiClient` but now it's different its throw `GoogleSignInClient` i don't have any clue how to set up popupview when user login or unlock an achievement. And even there is no good explanation for this in google docs so any one know it please post ur answer thanks in advance

```
//google variable
private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
private static final int RC_ACHIEVEMENT_UI = 9003;
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void SignIn(View view) {
    GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
            GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
    Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

private void signInSilently() {
    GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
            GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
    signInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(this,
            new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // The signed in account is stored in the task's result.
                        GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = task.getResult();
                    } else {
                        // Player will need to sign-in explicitly using via UI
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    signInSilently();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(requestCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        Log.d("fuck", String.valueOf(result));
        // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(result),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // The signed in account is stored in the result.
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Succesfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
        } else {
            String message = result.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
            if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
                message = getString(R.string.signin_other_error);
            }
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message)
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null).show();
        }
    }
}

public void achievement(View view) {

    Games.getAchievementsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .getAchievementsIntent()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_ACHIEVEMENT_UI);
                }
            });
}

public void unlock(View view) {
    Games.getAchievementsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .unlock(getString(R.string.achievement_newbie));
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok so i got the answer myself after giving couple of tries
what you can do is after successful sign in `task.getResult()` will return `GoogleSignInAccount` object you can pass that to `getGamesClient` method which will return a `GamesClient` object and using that object you can call `setViewForPopups` method. below is the clear code

```
private void signInSilently() {
    GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
            GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
    signInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(this,
            new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // The signed in account is stored in the task's result.
                        GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = task.getResult();
                        GamesClient gamesClient =Games.getGamesClient(MainActivity.this,signedInAccount);
                        gamesClient.setViewForPopups(findViewById(R.id.textview));
                    } else {
                        // Player will need to sign-in explicitly using via UI
                    }
                }
            });
}
```